# createTransferCheckedInstruction - invalid account data for instruction

Tags: spl-token, typescript

I'm trying to write instructions for transferring spl-tokens(not nft):

```
const transfer = createTransferCheckedInstruction(
    account_from.publicKey,
    mintId,
    account_desc.publicKey,
    account_from.publicKey,
    1,
    8
  )
```

Error log:

```
'Program log: Instruction: TransferChecked',
    'Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1357 of 599700 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: invalid account data for instruction'
```

**What am I doing wrong ?**

P.S.: may be account_from.publicKey and account_from.publicKey should be associated token account keys ? but i get error again.

Comment: I found these two links that might help you: https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#what-do-i-need-to-get-started-with-spl-tokens

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/a08ec509/token/js/src/instructions/transferChecked.ts

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say that the error hints that the from account doesn't have the correct data, i.e. doesn't own what you're trying to transfer

Comment: @CrossedCarpet yes, thx. I'm a little confused about the accounts, it's working now, apparently I needed a break)

Comment: Totally feel you... diving into crypto through solana has been an uphill battle for me. Be strong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you're using the `account_from.publicKey` as the source token account owner

```
const transfer = createTransferCheckedInstruction(
    account_from.publicKey,
    mintId,
    account_desc.publicKey,
    account_from.publicKey, // this should be owner of `acount_from` token account
    1,
    8
  )
```

Here is a [Solana Playground link](https://beta.solpg.io/6553a32dfb53fa325bfd0c16) you can reference.

Specifically here:

```
// Create transferChecked instruction
const instruction = createTransferCheckedInstruction(
  sourceTokenAccount.address, // source token account
  mint, // mint address
  destinationTokenAccount.address, // destination token account
  wallet_1.publicKey, // source token account owner
  100, // amount (1 token)
  2 // decimals of mint
);

// Create new transaction and add instruction
const transaction = new Transaction().add(instruction);

// Send transaction
const transactionSignature3 = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [wallet_1.keypair] // signer
);
```